# Problem associating CloudFront distribution with Route 53 domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am getting stuck while trying to secure my S3 hosted website. The steps I have followed are:

1. I have created a custom domain with Route 53, hosted on S3.
2. Created an SSL certificate.
3. Created a CloudFront distribution and and set it to use my ssl certificate, and given my custom domain as the CloudFront "alternate domain name"
4. Created a public hosted zone for my domain.
5. Created "A" and "AAAA" records to link my domain to my CloudFront distribution.

However, I cannot access my website, either HTTPS or just HTTP. But I can access the website through the CloudFront Domain name just fine. Just not when I tried to access it through my custom domain name. (`example.com`)

Comment: Did you set `Alias=Yes` in the Route 53 Record Set? See: [Routing Traffic to an Amazon CloudFront Web Distribution by Using Your Domain Name - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html)

Comment: *"I cannot access my website"* What exactly happens when you try to access the site using your domain?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I receive the message "This site can't be reached".

Answer (score 7):

You need to follow some steps to access your cloudfront distribution through a custom domain. Please check these 3 steps:

1 - Have you added a CNAME entry in cloudfront distribution as shown by the image below?

[image]

2 - All that you need in **ROUTE53** is create an **ALIAS** entry pointing to your cloudfront distribution. Have you added this? If your settings are right, Route53 will give you the option of your distribution which matches with your domain. (Make Sure that you have set CNAME entry). Please refer to the image below:

[image]

3 - For last, please make sure that your SSL match with your domain.

I believe that you probably missing CNAME entry as described by step 1.

Comment: I was struggling with this for a few days already on my pet project... My issue was I wanted to use both the _www.example.com_ and _example.com_ addresses. It was working with one but not with the other, I got 403 CloudFront errors, but the direct URLs based on the CF distribution URLs were working. What I was missing is having both the _www.example.com_ and _example.com_ addresses in the _Alternate Domain Names_ section. Thx for the hint, Lucas!